# Navigation drawer is not hiding in kivymd while using nested screenmanagers

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

```
MDScreen:
MDNavigationLayout:
    ScreenManager:
        MDScreen:
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation:'vertical'
                MDToolbar:
                    title:"Teacher Section"
                    left_action_items:[["menu",lambda x:nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                    right_action_items:[["magnify",lambda x:None]]
                    elevation:5
                MDScreen:
                    ScreenManager:
                        id:nestedsm
                        MDScreen:
                            name:"Screen1"
                            MDLabel:
                                text:"Screen1"
                        MDScreen:
                            name:"Screen2"
                            MDLabel:
                                text:"Screen2"

                Widget:
            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                ContentNavigationDrawer:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: "8dp"
                    spacing: "8dp"
                    Image:
                        id: avatar
                        size_hint: (1,1)
                        source: "images/kitten.png"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Bhushan Ghevde"
                        font_style: "Subtitle1"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "bhushanghevde15@gmail.com"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        font_style: "Caption"
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                    ScrollView:
                        DrawerList:
                            id: md_list

                            MDList:
                                OneLineIconListItem:
                                    text: "Add Teacher"
                                    on_release:
                                        nestedsm.current = 'Screen1'



                                    IconLeftWidget:
                                        icon: "face-profile"



                                OneLineIconListItem:
                                    text: "Upload"
                                    on_release:
                                        nestedsm.current = 'Screen2'

                                    IconLeftWidget:
                                        icon: "upload"
```

I am creating a collage level app for manageing student details . The Normal Screenmanager works perfectly fine . while i was trying nested Screen manager i am facing problems . the problem is , when i try to change screen from navigation drawer , it changes screen but doesnt hide automatically , i have to click back again to hide. any help is appreciated . Thank you in advanced..

[i have provided video of issue](https://youtu.be/dw99n8YWfZs)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, you can add the line:

```
root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state(new_state='toggle', animation=True)
```

Under the "on_release" of every list item, if you are adding those using the "for loop", you should add them like:

```
self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.md_list.add_widget(OneLineIconListItem(icon=icon_name, text="Item number 1", on_release=lamda x:(self.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state(new_state='toggle', animation=True))))
```

Or you can just implement it inside of the kivy lang:

```
Screen:
    #MDNavigationLayout: #unknown class 
    ScreenManager:
        Screen:
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation:'vertical'
                MDToolbar:
                    title:"Teacher Section"
                    left_action_items:[["menu",lambda x:nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                    right_action_items:[["magnify",lambda x:None]]
                    elevation:5
                MDScreen:
                    ScreenManager:
                        id:nestedsm
                        MDScreen:
                            name:"Screen1"
                            MDLabel:
                                text:"Screen1"
                        MDScreen:
                            name:"Screen2"
                            MDLabel:
                                text:"Screen2 jbsidis"

                Widget:
            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: "8dp"
                    spacing: "8dp"
                    Image:
                        id: avatar
                        size_hint: (1,1)
                        source: "images/pro.jpg" #"images/kitten.png"
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Bhushan Ghevde"
                        font_style: "Subtitle1"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "bhushanghevde15@gmail.com"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        font_style: "Caption"
                        height: self.texture_size[1]
                    ScrollView:
                        MDList:
                            id: md_list
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: "Add Teacher"
                                on_release:
                                    nestedsm.current = 'Screen1'
                                    root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state(new_state='toggle', animation=True)
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: "face-profile"

                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: "Upload"
                                on_release:
                                    nestedsm.current = 'Screen2'
                                    root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state(new_state='toggle', animation=True)
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: "upload"
```

Picture:
[image]

Comment: thank you so much , I really appreciate this i will try this today itself ....